# Was this question about train schedules closed appropriately?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question has been put on hold:

[Traveling from Frankfurt to Karlsruhe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141927/traveling-from-frankfurt-to-karlsruhe)

The reason is

> "Questions covering tasks normally performed by travel agents such as constructing travel and tour itineraries (including scheduling and budgeting) are off-topic. They are generally too specific to your personal preference, with many variables and possibilities, and are probably not helpful to others. See also The WANTA debate."

I get that the number of people wanting this exact train is going to be vanishingly small.

But the information given in the *exceedingly* helpful accepted answer by a *fine* member of our community is very applicable to other such questions.  The link shows what such a train schedule looks like and explains how to interpret it, and also shows how to understand the station diagram in order to know how to change trains.

Currently the answer is as specific as the question.  But suppose the answer were rewritten to include more general resources so as to teach the OP to fish, so to speak.  Would that make the question-and-answer appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was reopened six hours and 23 minutes after this meta question was posted.